# SAS/SQL join based on one column pattern matches another column

Tags: sql, string, sas, inner-join, sql-like

I have 2 datasets that I need to match on a id field:

**data1:**

```
id
---------
00123abc5
```

**data2:**

```
id
---
23a
```

I need to merge (SQL style `inner join`) these two datasets on `id` column but not `data1.id = data2.id`. What I want is `data1.id contains data2.id`.

So I want all rows where the `id` string in the first dataset contains the `id` string of the second dataset.

Comment: the answer is going to be some form of LIKE statement, but be warned:  if the value in data2 is as short as your sample is, then unless your complete datasets are VERY small, there's a very good chance you are going to find multiple matches per data2 entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL, use the `LIKE` operator :

```
SELECT d1.id
FROM data1 d1 
INNER JOIN data2 d2 ON d1.id LIKE CONCAT('%', d2.id, '%')
```

---

As commented by TheMouseMaster, this technique might generate duplicated output rows if several ids happen to be found in the same field. You can use `DISTINCT` to eliminate the duplicates :

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.id
FROM data1 d1 
INNER JOIN data2 d2 ON d1.id LIKE CONCAT('%', d2.id, '%')
```

Comment: it really comes down to what the result is designed to do.  He could easily end up with 2 tables that only have 3 lines each, but have a 9-record resulting table.  If that is what he wants, then it's all good, of course :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use index function

```
data have;
input id $9.;
datalines;
00123abc5
00543abc5
;
data have1;
input id $ col1;
datalines;
23a 22
43a 72
73a 82
;

  proc sql;
   create table want as 
  select a.id, col1
  from have a
  inner join
  have1 b
 on index(a.id, trim(b.id)) gt 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` if you only want the rows from one table:

```
select d1.id
from data1 d1
where exists (select 1 from data2 d2 where d1.id like concat('%', d2.id, '%');
```

Actually, in SAS, I would use the standard concatenation operator:

```
select d1.id
from data1 d1
where exists (select 1 from data2 d2 where d1.id like '%' || d2.id || '%';
```